# C user defined function issues

Tags: c, sqlite, function

I am testing `sqlite3` with `C` and I decided to make a simple program that takes a username and password from input in a function and passes it to be inserted into a `sqlite3` database table. Problem I have is that whenever I mention the function I wrote anywhere in my code I get an error like this for each mention:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘register’
 void *register(const char *u,const char *p)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sqlite3.h>

void register(const char *u,const char *p)
{
 printf("Enter your desired username: \n");
 scanf("%s", u);
 printf("Enter your desired password: \n");
 scanf("%s", p);    
}


int main()
{
const char new_user[50];
const char new_pass[50];
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening Database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 0;
}


char *sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?, ?, '0335804828', 'Strada userului nr 9', NULL, 0);";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

 if (rc == SQLITE_OK) 
{        
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "blala", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "blabla", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
} 
else 
{        
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

return 0;
}
```

As you can see code is not yet finished but it does not compile because of the mentioned error.
I've searched for similar answers but nothing worked in my case. I've tried changing the function and its types but nothing works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude of course... how dumb of me.. thanks

Comment: Another problem is that you pass pointers to *constant* characters to your function. That means you can't modify the contents of the arrays (like using them as targets in `scanf`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my other problem with that is that the sqlite3_bind_text uses const char* to pass as an actual argument to insert into table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> void register(const char *u,const char *p)
> {
>  printf("Enter your desired username: \n");
>  scanf("%s", u);
>  printf("Enter your desired password: \n");
>  scanf("%s", p);    
> }
> ```

Two issues. You use `register` as a function name, but it is the C keyword which cannot be used.

When you change the name your function parameters are wrong. `const char *u` means that bytes referenced by 'u' are `const` and cannot be changed.

```
void foo(char *u,char *p);
```

or if the pointers do not change

```
void foo(char * const u,char * const p);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`register` is a keyword in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/register). You can't use keywords for names.